# Converting a locator into xpath in Capybara

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

Im using Capybara & I am trying to find some xpath that may or may not exist on a page.
I would like to be able to use a selector that I created myself (:tab_is_selected), so that I could search for an xpath like:

page.should have_xpath(:tab_is_selected, selectable) 
Where selectable is the name of some tab.

If I use find, it just fails because the xpath does not always exist.

Does anyone know if there is some library in Capybara that could allow me to do this?
Otherwise I will have to write my own module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using:

```
page.has_selector?(:xpath, selectable).should == false
```

and

```
page.has_css?(selectable).should == true
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers

Comment: Thanks DavidC. That works quite well, its a lot better than just using find and getting an error. 
 
I have decided to use it like this: 

   `page.has_selector?(:tab_is_selected, tab_name).should == true`